# Make OCaml module signature manifest their types

Tags: types, module, ocaml

I have the following example:

```ml
module type S = sig
  type t

  val do_something : t -> unit
end

module Foo : S = struct
  type t = [`Foo of int | `Bar of string]

  let do_something _ = ()
end

module Baz : S = struct
  type t = [`Baz of char | `Qux of unit]

  let do_something _ = ()
end


let () =
  Foo.do_something (`Foo 1);
  Baz.do_something (`Qux ())
```

But when running this example, I get:

```
File "./m.ml", line 21, characters 19-27:
Error: This expression has type [> `Foo of int ]
       but an expression was expected of type Foo.t
```

Basically, from my understanding, [it looks like `S.t` is absract.](https://ocaml.org/learn/faq.html#Module-Language). And the may to make it "manifest", is to define it. (For example `type t = something`.)

But the issue is that this type changes between `Foo` and `Bar`.

Is there a way to make `S.t` manifest in its signature, without knowing what its value will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed that the signature constraint

```
module Baz : S = struct
  type t = [`Baz of char | `Qux of unit]
  let do_something _ = ()
end
```

makes the type `Baz.t` abstract. Moreover, this renders the module `Baz` useless because there is no way left to produce a value of type `Baz.t`.

The simplest solution is to remove the signature constraint. This is less surprising if you remember that signature constraints only remove information and the typing of module is structural. In particular, this means that

```
 module Do_twice(X:S) = struct
   let do_twice x = X.do_something x; X.do_something x
 end
 module Baz = struct
   type t = [`Baz of char | `Qux of unit]
   let do_something _ = ()
 end
 module Twice_Baz= Do_twice(Baz)
 let () = Twice_Baz.do_twice (`Baz 'a')
```

works as expected.

If you want to have an explicit signature constraint, you need to be careful to not remove any useful information. The right way to do it is to add more information about the type `t` in the module type `S` with a `with` constraint:

```
 module Baz: S with type t = [`Baz of char | `Qux of unit]  = struct
   type t = [`Baz of char | `Qux of unit]
   let do_something _ = ()
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the interface just take on the definition of something else depending on use would kind of defeat the purpose of using a shared interface, I think. However, you can "extend" a signature, in a sense, by adding a type constraint to it, e.g. `S with type t = ...`. The "extended" signature would also remain compatible with the original.

Here's your example, made to compile using type constraints:

```
module type S = sig
  type t

  val do_something : t -> unit
end

module Foo : S with type t = [`Foo of int | `Bar of string] = struct
  type t = [`Foo of int | `Bar of string]

  let do_something _ = ()
end

module Baz : S with type t = [`Baz of char | `Qux of unit] = struct
  type t = [`Baz of char | `Qux of unit]

  let do_something _ = ()
end


let () =
  Foo.do_something (`Foo 1);
  Baz.do_something (`Qux ())
```